# Can someone share an example of consuming dynamodb streams using KCL2 Java library

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have been trying to use KCL2 library for reading data from DynamoDB streams. However i am running into following error -

```
2022-06-09 11:51:50.717 ERROR [pay-orch-public-apis,,] 959982 --- [      Thread-13] s.amazon.kinesis.leases.ShardSyncTask    : Caught exception while sync'ing Kinesis shards and leases

software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:000000000000:table/merchant/stream/2022-06-08T19:08:14.229' at 'streamName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+ (Service: Kinesis, Status Code: 400, Request ID: e6cfe0b7-7cd7-5469-bdd4-73098777541e, Extended Request ID: coIxVZGZPtfiq/NewMV3/vIPXBtEAL+S1kJD0fvOK52qw8ZDbSwvyzr/j+ZsJEUe1/NGr4zgppY411AgqCHIkYoTp5bE+RS6)
```

I was wondering if there are any examples of DynamoDB streams consumption using KCL2 library as i could find quite a few for KCL 1 but none for KCL 2.

Answer (score 0):

After running into the same issue, I discovered dynamodb streams aren’t supported by KCL v2 at this time: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html